# Building Android user interfaces at runtime with layouts from server

Tags: android, layout

Looking at an earlier question [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942104/building-using-runtime-generated-layout-xml-in-android) based on the same concept,is there an approach to do this via the LayoutInflator?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question (or the answers to the previous question), but it looks like they specifically say that you can't do that. Someone there quotes "it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime" from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping someone has found a workround on the "it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime".
Well I guess i'll have to go the "do it yourself" way in this one.

Comment: Android Framework uses the mechanism called as dependency injection to create a view hierarchy from xml layouts. So to build user interface runtime with layouts from server you need to checkout android open source code how they are doing and then you can build you own implementation of it.