# Create, store and inflate custom layout in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem. The application I work on requires a possibility for user to produce custom UI (layout of simple widgets) via custom UI builder. So, user may stack widgets (images, mostly. But TextViews and EditText, as well) on canvas, move them around, etc.
UI have to be stored in a database for future use. So, there should be some mechanism for loading and inflating of this UI. This is the main problem.

My first idea was to rely on standard Android layout mechanism. Unfortunately, the LayoutInflater works with XML compiled into a binary form. And as far as I know, it's not possible to compile an XML string into binary representation in runtime.

Does, anybody have experience with such problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building/using runtime generated layout XML in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942104/building-using-runtime-generated-layout-xml-in-android)

Comment: considering that you will be implementing some subset of the layout functionality in your editor it may make sense to roll your own representation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the inflate methods of [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). You can actually give it any `XmlPullParser` to use as its source, which in turn can be constructed given any `Reader`.

In other words, you can use just about any character stream as your xml source for inflating.

The beginning of the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) docs gives you the basic outline for creating the pull parser:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(new StringReader("<foo>Hello World!</foo>"));
```

**Update** - this isn't going to work, as mentioned in the `LayoutInflater` docs.

Comment: This doesn't work with xml layouts actually. If you pass a simple XML to XmlPullParser, and then try to call inflater.inflate(xpp, null) method, it will throw you an exception

Comment: And the reason is - the LayoutInflater itself uses XmlBlock.Parser, a parser created to work with binary from of xml layouts. While XmlPullParserFactory creates an instance of simple org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser

Comment: I stand corrected! Thank you for pointing that out. Then, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942104/building-using-runtime-generated-layout-xml-in-android

Comment: Yes, seems like a duplicate. It's so strange that there's no facility available to inflate layout from a string... Even if the performance is not good, so what?..

Comment: Do it in Java then. Parse the XML, and then create the necessary Views with the required properties. Then let us know how it performs ;)